# Converting sparse matrix to sparse data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sparse-matrix, pca

I want to conduct a rpca and had a dataframe df before.

`rpca(df, k = 1000, center = FALSE, scale = TRUE, retx = TRUE, p = 10,
+      q = 2, rand = TRUE)`

I got the error message: "cannot allocate vector of size 500mb"

So I created a sparse matrix m and repeated the rpca (not knowing that this would be larger than the original df) so I got the error message

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.5 Gb

Is there a way to transform this sparse matrix to a sparse dataframe?

Note: I know there are entries here on converting sparse matrix to a dataframe, but since the dataframe was already too large I am looking for a sparse dataframe, which I couldn't find anything on...Any help is highly appreciated. (please bear in mind I am new to ml and r)

Comment: I don't know of any implementation of sparse frames. In order to support that, there would also need to be sparse vectors.

Comment: ... and it sounds like you don't want to convert so much as have `rpca` *create* something sparse. Suggestions: (1) reduce your existing memory footprint, looking at `sapply(ls(), object.size)` for an idea of what is huge, perhaps starting with a fresh instance of R to be certain; (2) [reach out to the author](https://github.com/macieksk/rpca/issues) to see if alternatives might be implemented; (3) get more RAM :-)

Comment: Ok good to know, thanks for the alternative recommendations! :)